# How to copy Simulink Blocks to Simulink library programmatically

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am trying to copy Simulink Blocks from Models to a library programmatically. I have a several Simulink models with the same name in different folders. I want to iterate over them and copy the blocks from these models into a Simulink library. Something like this:

```
function UpdateLibrary()
    %UPDATELIBRARY Updates  BlockLib.mdl form PLECSBlocks of Components
    %   Detailed explanation goes here
    UserLibDir = SimulationManagerClass.Dir.UserLib; %get the path
    if exist([SimulationManagerClass.Dir.UserLib, '\BlockLib.mdl'], 'file')
        delete([SimulationManagerClass.Dir.UserLib, '\BlockLib.mdl']);  
    end
    BlockLib = new_system('BlockLib', 'Library'); %empty library
    PlecsBlocks = rdir([SimulationManagerClass.Dir.UserLib, '\**\PLECSBlock.mdl']); %get all my sources
    for i = 1:numel(PlecsBlocks)
        SystemPath = PlecsBlocks(i).name;
        sys = load_system(PlecsBlocks(i).name);
        Blocks = find_system(sys);
        add_block(Blocks(2),BlockLib);
        close_system(sys);
    end
    save_system(BlockLib, [SimulationManagerClass.Dir.UserLib, '\BlockLib.mdl']);
    close_system(BlockLib);
end
```

Right now I am trying to copy just one block. Blocks seems to contain the handle of the complet model as well so:

```
Block(1) == sys
```

When I try this I get:

```
Invalid destination block specification
```

Can add_block not copy to a library? Is it possible to do it somehow?

Best regards

Lukas

Answer (score 1):

For add_block you need to provide destination path as the second argument.

```
add_block(Blocks{2}, 'BlockLib/destination_name');
```

You need to use cell paren for `Blocks` to get the path name of source. If you want destination to have same name as original block you may need to extract `destination_name` from `Blocks{2}` by removing the source model name.

Comment: Nice. It worked. I just had to pass a string as argument. Thanks, mate!